# Is it possible to use a fingerprint reader with Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, fingerprint

I recently purchased a K-Byte Fingerprint Reader, it says something about using it on the web but nothing on how to do so. I successfully set it up with Windows Hello, however, is there a chrome extension for this? If not, is there any possible way to do so without the extension?

Comment: Did you get a CD with the device, and did you install it? Which version of Windows?

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10. It says as a note not to use the cd if you have windows 10. I use it with Windows Hello though

Comment: Yes, if you have the needed Software you can use your fingerprint. Just google "biometric Authentication with Chrome Support". You should find some results. You just have to read the requirements and check if your Fingerprint Reader is supported.

Comment: Did you try to run it before you installed the CD? It might be that the drivers on the CD are too old.

Comment: @harrymc listen, it's not a problem with the driver. The sensor works fine, I just need an extension for it to work.

Comment: What do you want this extension to do?

Comment: @harrymc to sign in to an account using my fingerprint. The box said "login using your fingerprint to sign in on web and computer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a LastPass Premium account, LastPass has a biometric authentication option. You can enable it by opening My Vault, then Settings, then Multifactor Options.

Comment: And if I don't?

Comment: @AbAppletic then it's up to you to find web-compatie 3-rd party software

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to this site http://support.authentec.com/Downloads/Windows/ProtectorSuite.aspx and download protector suite, should work for windows 7 and 8.

2) Go back to the site above, click on Browser Extension tab and click download for chrome

3) Look for the downloaded file, and drag file with your mouse to your opened chrome browser into your extensions. Fingerprint reader should work with chrome now.

Comment: The link is invalid...